# Pandas Filtering and Grouping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to  group methods column,this df's methods column is categorical variable but I couldnt group them.When I ran this code the result was separetly,I mean not grouped as methods.Could you help me ?

```
import seaborn as sns
df=sns.load_dataset("planets")
df
    
def filter_functionn(x):
      return x["orbital_period"].std()>50
    
df.groupby(["method"]).filter(filter_functionn)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for repeat aggregate values, so possible filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df.groupby("method")["orbital_period"].transform('std') > 50]
print (df)
               method  number  orbital_period   mass  distance  year
0     Radial Velocity       1      269.300000   7.10     77.40  2006
1     Radial Velocity       1      874.774000   2.21     56.95  2008
2     Radial Velocity       1      763.000000   2.60     19.84  2011
3     Radial Velocity       1      326.030000  19.40    110.62  2007
4     Radial Velocity       1      516.220000  10.50    119.47  2009
              ...     ...             ...    ...       ...   ...
1030          Transit       1        3.941507    NaN    172.00  2006
1031          Transit       1        2.615864    NaN    148.00  2007
1032          Transit       1        3.191524    NaN    174.00  2007
1033          Transit       1        4.125083    NaN    293.00  2008
1034          Transit       1        4.187757    NaN    260.00  2008

[1035 rows x 6 columns]
```